# Use a std::shared_ptr as a global variable in Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I'm trying to implement a class from my c++ .h-file together with shared_ptr:s.

Why doesn't my shared_ptr (totPtr) keep its value between the methods?

Example code when I've use a double instead of the class:

```
#include <memory>

static std::shared_ptr<myCppClass> totPtr;
static double tot; 


@implementation ViewController


- (void) createSelf
{
    totPtr = std::make_shared<myCppClass>(5); 
    tot = 10;   
}
```

This method is called after createSelf:

```
- (void)otherMethod 
{
    tot += 1; // works, tot = 11
    totPtr->doStuff(); // doesn't work, totPtr = nullptr 

}
```

tot2 still has has the value = 0, but tot has the value = 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For global variables, you should initialized it in [`+[initialize]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize), which is a thread-safe way to initialize any global variables

```
+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [ViewController self]) { // need to guard it so not get called again from subclass
        totPtr = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
        tot = 10;
    }
}
```

If you initialize them in `viewDidLoad`, it may works now, but when you decide to have multiple instance of `ViewController`, you will find the second call of `viewDidLoad` will reset these gloabl variables.

**BUT** normally you don't want global variable, you want instance variable / property

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) double tot;
@end

@implementation ViewController {
    std::shared_ptr<myCppClass> _totPtr;
}
```

which you can initailize them in `viewDidLoad` which described in the other answer.

Note: I *don't* recommended to use ObjC property with C++ class (i.e. `shared_ptr`). Because everytime you access it via property, it require overhead of call a setter/getter method which may need to copy `shared_ptr`, which is an expansive operation (you should always pass `shared_ptr` by reference in method argument, but this doesn't have good support in ObjC). Access ivar directly allow you to avoid the overhead.

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to use global variables - better to use properties.

But if you still need it - don't use init method for it.

On yours code i don't see who is calling createSelf method.

Here i show working code.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyClass.h"
#include <memory>

static std::shared_ptr<MyClass> totPtr;
static double tot;

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) std::shared_ptr<MyClass> p1;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self m1];
    [self m2];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void) m1{
    totPtr = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
    self.p1 = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
    tot = 10;
}

-(void) m2{
    NSLog(@"id: %d",self.p1->id());
    NSLog(@"id: %d",totPtr->id());
}

- (IBAction)ev1:(id)sender {
    [self m2];
}

@end
```

**Update:**

You could use this method if you want to init that var in init* method

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder*
```